# ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('')

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to send a video to software and get the analysis results. To start tried to connect to the software using the following code.

```
import socket,cv2, pickle,struct
# create socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_ip = '127.0.0.1' # paste your server ip address here
port = 9090
client_socket.connect((host_ip,port)) # a tuple
```

I got the connection success from this part. Next I tried to get a sample output from the software.

```
response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:9090")
```

I encounter the following error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine(',\x01\x00\x002\x00\x00\x00FaceReaderAPI.Messages.PresentationResponseMessage<?xml version="1.0"?>\r\n'))
```

I tried HTTPS as well.
Can someone please help me solving this issue?

Comment: First you create a TCP/IP socket `client_socket` but then you do a HTTP request using `requests`. What is `requests`?

Comment: It appears the other software is not a HTTP server.

Comment: Thank you rveerd I understand. Solved!